# dplyr filtering with lubridate::hhmm format with minute()

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, lubridate

Answering this question [Temperature curve in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45800370/3250126) I came across a weird behavior of a `dplyr::filter` - `lubridate::minute` combination.

See the test data `dta` below. `dta$time` is a `lubridate::hhmm` format.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dta$Time <- hm(dta$Time)
```

To get only rows with full hours (i.e. 0 minutes) one can subset using `lubridate::minute` like this:

```
dta[minute(dta$Time) == 0,]
#        Time    Temp1    Temp2
# 1        0S 18.62800 18.54458
# 7  1H 0M 0S 18.45733 18.22625
# 13 2H 0M 0S 18.33258 18.04142
```

However, when using `dplyr`'s `filter`, like this

```
dta %>% filter(minute(Time) == 0)
#     Time    Temp1    Temp2
# 1     0S 18.62800 18.54458
# 2 10M 0S 18.45733 18.22625
# 3 20M 0S 18.33258 18.04142
```

the result does not really fit the expectation. (**UPDATE**: The values of `Temp1` and `Temp2` are correct, only `Time` is corrupt... Thanks to [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330437/brian) btw for giving this hint. )

Additionally this warning is returned:

> `Warning message:
>   In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
>     corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs`

This was also reported and somehow solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43853371/3250126), but only by coercion, which seems to remove the fun (and very readable) part of lubridate.

**Question**: Is there any way (to date) to `dplyr::filter` `lubridate::hhmm(ss)` formats without coercing it to character etc.?

### Update:

It seems that the vector created by

```
minute(dta$Time)
# [1]  0 10 20 30 40 50  0 10 20 30 40 50  0
```

looks like a numeric vector, yet seems to have some mysterious characteristics.

Furthermore, as @Lyngbakr pointed out even the comparison with `==` does not have the usual characteristics as a "normal" logical vector.

```
tst <- minute(dta$Time) == 0 
dta %>% filter(tst)
```

will result in the same strange `Time` column.

#### Sample data:

```
dta <- read.table(text = "     Time        Temp1       Temp2
                           1  00:00     18.62800    18.54458
                           2   00:10     18.60025    18.48283
                           3   00:20     18.57250    18.36767
                           4   00:30     18.54667    18.36950
                           5   00:40     18.51483    18.36550
                           6   00:50     18.48325    18.34783
                           7   01:00     18.45733    18.22625
                           8   01:10     18.43767    18.19067
                           9   01:20     18.41583    18.22042
                           10  01:30     18.39608    18.21225
                           11  01:40     18.37625    18.18658
                           12  01:50     18.35633    18.05942
                           13  02:00     18.33258    18.04142", header = T)
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems that `filter` cannot deal with `Formal class 'Period'`. If you gather first and try to filter (`dta %>% gather(var, val, -Time) %>% filter(minute(Time) == 0)`) it throws an error `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 26, not 13`

Comment: What I find particularly strange is that even if you use an intermediate variable, it persists. For example, `tst <- minute(dta$Time) == 0` and then `dta %>% filter(tst)`. As far as I can see, `tst` is just a regular logical vector.

Comment: All the columns **except** `Time` are being correctly `filter`ed. I tried making an intermediate variable `mutate(mins = minutes(Time))` and filtering on that, and the correct rows were returned, but not for the `Time` column.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this works, but it does: The `Time` column needs to be of type `datetime`, not `Period`.

```
dta %>% 
  mutate(Time = as_datetime(hm(Time))) %>% 
  filter(minute(Time) == 0)
```

> ```
>                  Time    Temp1    Temp2
> 1 1970-01-01 00:00:00 18.62800 18.54458
> 2 1970-01-01 01:00:00 18.45733 18.22625
> 3 1970-01-01 02:00:00 18.33258 18.04142
> ```

This has the side effect of just adding the time in the `Time` column to the Unix epoch, so I would advise always including an actual date when you're using time-only data.

If this were minutes elapsed since the start of an experiment, it doesn't really matter that much, you don't have to display the 1970-01-01 part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to this post. However, since there is still some coercion to a datetime format necessary, I will not yet mark it as accepted, to keep the discussion going.

Comment: @loki, I think S4 classes, like Period, just don't play well with dataframes. They have six slots, instead of being a single-value in a vector. From looking at `?lubridate::\`Period-class\``, I gather that any arithmetic on them is done under the hood by coercing to seconds first and then back-coercing.

Comment: Yes, seems like that. but as @Lyngbakr pointed out It seems like even if  `str(minute(dta$Time))
 num [1:13] 0 10 20 30 40 50 0 10 20 30 ..` is a numeric vector, it is not handled like one (or a logical when comparing it via `==`).

Comment: Yes, and when I tried that, it returned the correct rows of the data (Temp1 and Temp2), but not the correct rows of Time.

Comment: Now, as you point that out, it is getting even more confusing. I will update the Q, to see if anyone has an idea on that... Thanks for pointing that out.